# regular expressions in SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I need to verify an ESN number using javascript. i  was quite successful to succeed it by using a simple regular expression and an if statement:

```
 $('#ESN_val').on('keyup', function () {
                var ESN = document.getElementById('ESN_val').value;
                if (/^[0-9A-F]{8}$/.test(ESN) && ESN.length == 8) {              
                alert('valid ESN')
                }else{
                    'invalid ESN'
                } 
            });
```

Now I just need to get the same result from sql once the whole data contains within the table as attached . [Table tsp_filtered_data name:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNXCv.png)

I need the query in the below format. There should be a new column and it should include 'valid ESN' or 'Invalid ESN'

```
SELECT
tsp_filtered_data.Document_id,
tsp_filtered_data.ESN,
(**********Regular Expresseion********) AS ESN_status 
FROM
tsp_filtered_data
```

Kindly tell me the query that I should include.

Comment: _thank you chamath_ You thank yourself? add 2 space after the line then only enter key works in output

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CASE WHEN and an [RLIKE/REGEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) should do.

```
SELECT
t.Document_id,
t.ESN,
case when t.ESN RLIKE '^[0-9A-F]{8}$' then 'valid ESN' else 'invalid ESN'  end AS ESN_status 
FROM
tsp_filtered_data t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator to check for a match. It will return 0 or 1 as a result.

```
SELECT
tsp_filtered_data.Document_id,
tsp_filtered_data.ESN,
tsp_filtered_data.ESN REGEXP '^[0-9A-F]{8}$' AS ESN_status 
FROM
tsp_filtered_data
```